# SharedPreferences in Android Studio Clicker App Not Working

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am creating a simple clicker program. I am clicking a pear picture and then it increments by 1 and displays that. I want to save this number so I they can click and then completely exit the app and when they return the same number they left off at is still there. This is my code but yet it still does not save that pears int when I restart the app.

CODE:

```
    package pearclicker.pearclicker;

    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageButton;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButtonPear;
    TextView showValue;
    int pears;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countText);
    }


    public void PearIncrease(View v) {
        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PearCount", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("pearCount", pears);
        pears++;
        if (pears == 1) {
        showValue.setText(pears + " pear");
            editor.putInt("pearCount", pears);
            editor.apply();
        }
        else {
            showValue.setText(pears + " pears");
            editor.putInt("pearCount", pears);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you're not getting the value of your sharedpreference pearCount. use `pref.getInt("pearCount", 0);` to get the value of your pearCount.

Comment: How does the preference know that the int is pears then? It will just store 0 then and not the int pears that is pears++ right?

Comment: because your preference editor is inserting it.

Comment: So where do I put the pref.getInt("pearCount", 0) in?

Comment: "How does the preference know that the int is pears then?" Because you tell it to by assigning a value to `pears`. You need to get the value that you stored in SharedPreferences and display it. Saving the value of a variable named `pears` does not mean that the value will be loaded back into that same variable automatically.

Comment: In `onCreate()` put `pears = pref.getInt("pearCount", 0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing fine when clicking the button to increase the value of your pear. but you're doing nothing in your `onCreate()` so you think that the `SharedPreference` is not storing the value of `pear` when you restart the app..

to do that you need some modification to your code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButtonPear;
    TextView showValue;
    int pears = 0;

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("PearCount", MODE_PRIVATE);

        showValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countText);

        pears = pref.getInt("pearCount", 0); // This will get the value of your pearCount, It will return Zero if its empty or null.
        showValue.setText(pears + " pears");
    }


    public void PearIncrease(View v) {
        editor = pref.edit();
        pears++;
        showValue.setText(pears + " pears");
        editor.putInt("pearCount", pears);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The only reason I had the if else statements was because when you say "1 pears" it is incorrect grammar

Comment: @Nick try this `showValue.setText(pears + ( pears == 1 ? " pear" : " pears")) ;`